# Variance in data in/out of loop

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I'm trying to write a program that reads in a .pdb file, which is a file type used in biology applications. This type of file has a standard format with varying white space between data. The file is of the form

```
ATOM      4  N   ALA     1       2.670   1.801   1.072  0.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  ALA     1       3.225   3.144   1.197  0.00  0.00
ATOM      6  C   ALA     1       4.408   3.341   0.256  0.00  0.00
ATOM      7  O   ALA     1       4.553   4.394  -0.363  0.00  0.00
....      .  ..  ...     .       .....   .....   .....  ..... ....
```

So my program (probably poorly written) defines a structure, reads in the data (which I stole from another post here http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/65455/reading-a-file-using-fscanf#), and stores it into an indexed struct. Now if I print the values inside of the inner if-loop, it spits out the correct data. However, when I print out the same values outside the outer while-loop, it gives me the wrong atom[].name (which just so happens to be HA, the last value in the 3rd column of data in the input file. All other values are correct.

Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
   char *atm;
   int serial;
   char *name;
   char *resName;
   int resSeq;
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
   double occupancy;
   double tempFactor;
} pdb;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int i, j;
   pdb atom[28]; 
   char atm[5]; 
   char name[3]; 
   char resName[4];
   int serial; 
   int resSeq;
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
   double occupancy;
   double tempFactor;
   char buff[BUFSIZ];
   FILE *file = fopen("test.pdb", "r");

   i = 0;
   while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) != NULL) 
   {
      if (sscanf(buff, "%s %d %s %s %d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", 
         atm, &serial, name, resName, &resSeq, &x, &y, &z, 
         &occupancy, &tempFactor) == 10)
      {
         atom[i].atm = atm;
         atom[i].serial = serial;
         atom[i].name = name;
         atom[i].resName = resName;
         atom[i].resSeq = resSeq;
         atom[i].x = x;
         atom[i].y = y;
         atom[i].z = z;
         atom[i].occupancy = occupancy;
         atom[i].tempFactor = tempFactor;
         i++;
         /*printf("%s ", atom[i].atm);
         printf("%d ", atom[i].serial);
         printf("%s ", atom[i].name);
         printf("%s ", atom[i].resName);
         printf("%d ", atom[i].resSeq);
         printf("%lf ", atom[i].x);
         printf("%lf ", atom[i].y);
         printf("%lf ", atom[i].z);
         printf("%lf ", atom[i].occupancy);
         printf("%lf\n", atom[i].tempFactor);*/
      }
   }
   fclose(file);
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
      printf("%d of %d: %s\n", j, i-1, atom[j].name);

   return(0);
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening? In addition, any help on the program format/structure would also be appreciated. I'm more of a Fortran guy, so C structures are out of my realm of expertise.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** jsn helped me out and Randy Howard refined it. Here is the updated and working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
   char *atm;
   int serial;
   char *name;
   char *resName;
   int resSeq;
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
   double occupancy;
   double tempFactor;
} pdb;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int i, j;
   pdb atom[28]; 
   int serial; 
   int resSeq;
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
   double occupancy;
   double tempFactor;
   char buff[BUFSIZ];
   FILE *file = fopen("test.pdb", "r");

   i = 0;
   while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) != NULL) 
   {
      char *atm = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5); 
      char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3); 
      char *resName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4); 

      if (sscanf(buff, "%s %d %s %s %d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", 
         atm, &serial, name, resName, &resSeq, &x, &y, &z, 
         &occupancy, &tempFactor) == 10)
      {
         atom[i].atm = atm;
         atom[i].serial = serial;
         atom[i].name = name;
         atom[i].resName = resName;
         atom[i].resSeq = resSeq;
         atom[i].x = x;
         atom[i].y = y;
         atom[i].z = z;
         atom[i].occupancy = occupancy;
         atom[i].tempFactor = tempFactor;
         i++;
      }
   }
   fclose(file);
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
         printf("%s ", atom[j].atm);
         printf("%d ", atom[j].serial);
         printf("%s ", atom[j].name);
         printf("%s ", atom[j].resName);
         printf("%d ", atom[j].resSeq);
         printf("%lf ", atom[j].x);
         printf("%lf ", atom[j].y);
         printf("%lf ", atom[j].z);
         printf("%lf ", atom[j].occupancy);
         printf("%lf\n", atom[j].tempFactor);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Show some expected output.

Comment: Expected output when priting atom[].name (from the above input file) should produce N, CA, C, O, but instead produced HA, HA, HA, HA, which is the last value in that column in the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the while loop you need to allocate new memory for each char* for each name. You are overwriting them right now.

```
while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) != NULL) 
{

    char *atm = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5); 
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3); 
    char *resName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4); 

    if (sscanf(buff, "%s %d %s %s %d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", 
             atm, &serial, name, resName, &resSeq, &x, &y, &z, 
             &occupancy, &tempFactor) == 10)
```

You are copying the char array (pointers), so all the names should be the same (the last entry).

Comment: If your char * fields have a constant maximum size you can define them in the struct as such. For example `char name[3];` instead of `char *name;`.

Comment: Don't cast malloc in C.  Although, should tell the OP that stdlib.h is required for malloc.

Comment: @RandyHoward, some of us have to work with Visual Studio. XD (C89)

Comment: If you use visual, but name your file .c instead of .cpp you shouldn't have an issue.  Otherwise, Visual is even more broken than I remembered.

Comment: If it truly requires you to cast malloc, with a stdlib.h included, and instructed to compile C instead of C++, then it's broken.  End of story.

Comment: @RandyHoward, I don't really care whether it is broken or not, but it is interesting that even '/TC` doesn't help.

Comment: Randy, are you saying jsn's solution (which works when using stdlib.h) is incorrect? Or a bad programming practice? And I'm not using Visual Studio.

Comment: @RandyHoward, there we go. I was using it wrong. stdlib.h + /Tcfilename.c works without casting malloc.

Comment: @mjswartz, almost everywhere besides Visual Studio (sometimes), you should not cast malloc. The only real reason I can think of is that may hide some small and subtle errors.

Comment: There are numerous "duplicate" questions (and FAQ's elsewhere) about casting in C versus C++.  It is bad practice in C, because it can actually mask errors in the code (for example, not having a valid prototype in scope).  Here's some more info: http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: @jsn It's a pity you have to work that hard to get Visual to behave as a C compiler.  I used it for more years than I like to remember in the past, and don't recall this being a problem.  I suspect it may have to do with how you set up the project initially, and compiler options, though.

Comment: @RandyHoward, I am just using VS's cl.exe compiler.

Comment: I will update my program with the uncasted solution. Thank you guys for the help.